# Get MongoDb Master Node from Slave

Tags: mongodb

In a master/slave mongodb setup, is there anyway to ask a slave node for it's master node?  Right now, I only know the dns name for a Mongo slave, but I'd like to be able to figure out the dns name of the master node.

Comment: In the slave call `rs.status` which shows you all members, where you can distinguish primary

Comment: @Markus W Mahlberg, I only have access to my production config which only contains the slaves; however, the slaves are read only.  So I need the master in order to write data to the cluster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to run `rs.status();` on the slave. It will return information for all the nodes.

Example output:

```
"members" : [
    {
        "_id" : 0,
        "name" : "m1.example.net:27017",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 1,
        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
        "uptime" : 269,
        "optime" : Timestamp(1404225575, 11),
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-05-01T14:39:35Z"),
        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1404225586, 1),
        "electionDate" : ISODate("2014-05-01T14:39:46Z"),
        "self" : true
    },
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "m2.example.net:27017",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 2,
        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
        "uptime" : 265,
        "optime" : Timestamp(1404225575, 11),
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-05-01T14:39:35Z"),
        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2014-05-01T14:44:03Z"),
        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2014-05-01T14:44:02Z"),
        "pingMs" : 0,
        "syncingTo" : "m1.example.net:27017"
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "name" : "m3.example.net:27017",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 2,
        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
        "uptime" : 265,
        "optime" : Timestamp(1404225575, 11),
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-05-01T14:39:35Z"),
        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2014-05-01T14:44:02Z"),
        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2014-05-01T14:44:02Z"),
        "pingMs" : 0,
        "syncingTo" : "m1.example.net:27017"
    }
]
```

Comment: A noob question, what does `rs` object stands for here?